# Reset Variable Counter after a fresh AJAX request. JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, closures, counter

Sorry If this Question is Trivial!! Well, I've a Page where I'm loading contents with AJAX.

Main Page (index.html):

```
<a href="#" id="loadContent">Load Remote Page</a>

<div id="ajaxContent">

//Loads AJAX contents Here!!

</div>
```

Remote Page (remote.html):

```
<h2 id="counter"></h2>
<button class="counterPlus" type="button">++</button>
```

jQuery (script.js):

```
$("#loadContent").on("click", function(){

        $.ajax({
                url: "remote.html",
                type: "GET",
                success: function(data){
                          $("#ajaxContent").html(data);
                }
        })

});

var counter = 1;
$("#ajaxContent").on("click", ".counterPlus", function(){
    console.log(counter);
    counter = counter + 1;
    $("#counter").text(counter);
});
```

On clicking the link in the Loaded page, I can see incremented value but the problem is Counter is not resetting After a fresh AJAX load (Click on the Link). I'm aware that old Variable value stays in Memory But What is the Solution to reset the Counter in this kinda Problem??

Comment: *"but the problem is Counter is not resetting"* There's nothing in the code that would make it reset. When do you want it to reset, and what would trigger that?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder After Clicking again in the Link, I need to reset. As per Solution from @ alexandru, That would work!! Thanks!! Cheers!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because your variable `counter` has **global** scope.

Just reset it inside the success callback function of ajax call.

```
var counter = 1;
$("#loadContent").on("click", function(){

    $.ajax({
            url: "remote.html",
            type: "GET",
            success: function(data){
                      counter = 1;
                      $("#ajaxContent").html(data);
            }
    })
});

$("#ajaxContent").on("click", ".counterPlus", function(){
    console.log(counter);
    counter = counter + 1;
    $("#counter").text(counter);
});
```

Comment: Yay..Got it that's because of Global Scope!! It Worked!! Thanks!! Cheers!!